# Long Polling causes Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-polling

I have this (attempt of) long polling function

I want to call this function in a certain time and then make the long polling work as long as the gallery has the `updating` class, gallery in this case is a `$("... ")`

```
function pollGallery(gallery){
    if (gallery.hasClass("updating")){
        var url = gallery.data("base") + "/refresh";
        $.ajax({ url: url, dataType: "script", complete: pollGallery(gallery), timeout: 30000 });
    }   
}
```

When I run this I get `Maximum call stack size exceeded` and from the logs it seems as if it doesn't either call the ajax or the timeout doesn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not passing a callback function to `complete`, it simply calls a function recursively infinitely.

```
    $.ajax({ url: url, dataType: "script", complete: function() {
        pollGallery(gallery);
    }, timeout: 30000 });
```

`complete` expects a **function** to be passed. By `complete: pollGallery(gallery)` you immediately call `pollGallery(gallery)` and attempt to assign its return value to the `complete` option, thus getting stuck in an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: ah thanks! thought it can be noted like the onclick notation. Thanks!

Comment: @NickGinanto yep, exactly. `;)` The callback pattern is the same, you must pass a function to be executed when a certain event happens (e.g. received network response, user clicked on an element).

Comment: I blame this http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: @NickGinanto well, the tutorial uses `complete: poll`, there `poll` is a function reference, so it is essentially passing a function to the `complete` option. It is different from `poll()` which is closer to your original case. `=]`